# Draw Mahalanobis distance for data with more than 3 dimensions

Tags: r, plot, distance, data-visualization

I have 4 dimensional data in a matrix, `group1`, that looks like the following:

```
     cost quality safety time
[1,]   13       6      3    4
[2,]   10       4      5   10
[3,]    8       9      3    9
[4,]    7       8      9    9
[5,]    4       4      4    2
```

I have another matrix, `group2`, that has a single row and four columns representing the same four variables:

```
     cost quality safety time
[1,]    2       2      7   11
```

To identify the distance between `group1` and `group2` I have calculated the Mahalanobis distance using the `mahalanobis` function:

```
mat1 <- matrix(group1, ncol=ncol(group1), dimnames=NULL)
mat2 <- matrix(group2, ncol=ncol(group2), dimnames=NULL)
mahalanobis(mat2, colMeans(mat1), cov(mat1))
```

The function calculates the distance from `group1` to `group2` as `13.74883`.

How can I draw the distance of `group2` from `group1` using Mahalanobis distance?

I also looked at `drawMahal` function from the `chemometrics` package ,but this function doesn't support more than 2 dimensions.

The graph is something like the following:

[image: position of group2 with respect to group1]

Comment: I mean that how can I draw the distance between group1 and group2, when each of these groups are multi-dimensional

Comment: What is your desired output? Is there a sample graph you can show? Do you want to draw the distance for each point?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have any sample graph that exactly show what I want.I want to show distance from group 1 to group 2, not each point of group 2, I want to consider group2 as a four dimensional point. I have updated my question